# Play video in a html page background

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, video

I want to use a video as a background instead of an image that automatically stretches to the whole screen (background).

I would also like to play the video for 5 sec just before the page content loads and also 5 sec before the user is redirected to another link as he clicked.

It would also be nice to know how to delay video playback, so that the video only plays once.

like if a page is loaded then just before the loading of the content a video playes for 5 sec then it pauses and again start playing if user clicks on another link,and the user will not be redirected before the video finishes.

Comment: So many duplicates when Googling `Play video in a html page background`

Comment: I know to to play a video on html page background as if you didn't read the full question.I just want to play the video before the content of the page loads and also just before a new link is opened

Answer (score 2):

You an use JQuery for this. You can just add your video URL and it can play it on your website background. Have a look.

[`JQuery Background Youtube Player`](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-tubular/)

[`Demo`](http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/)

Comment: i just want  to play before the content of the page loades and also just before a new link is opened